# Center multiple lines of text in Python

Tags: python

I want to centre this ASCII art in the centre of the terminal

```
    ____       ______               
   / __ \__  _/_  __/_  ______  ___ 
  / /_/ / / / // / / / / / __ \/ _ \
 / ____/ /_/ // / / /_/ / /_/ /  __/
/_/    \__, //_/  \__, / .___/\___/ 
      /____/     /____/_/
```

So far, my code is this

```
banner=['    ____       ______               ', '   / __ \__  _/_  __/_  ______  ___ ', '  / /_/ / / / // / / / / / __ \/ _ \ ', ' / ____/ /_/ // / / /_/ / /_/ /  __/', '/_/    \__, //_/  \__, / .___/\___/', '      /____/     /____/_/           ']
menulogo='\n'.join(banner)
menubanner=menulogo.center(300)

print(menubanner)
```

but the output is this (only the top part of the ASCII is centred)

```
                                           ____       ______               
   / __ \__  _/_  __/_  ______  ___ 
  / /_/ / / / // / / / / / __ \/ _ \ 
 / ____/ /_/ // / / /_/ / /_/ /  __/
/_/    \__, //_/  \__, / .___/\___/
      /____/     /____/_/
```

I would like some help on making the output something like this

```
                                   ____       ______               
                                  / __ \__  _/_  __/_  ______  ___ 
                                 / /_/ / / / // / / / / / __ \/ _ \ 
                                / ____/ /_/ // / / /_/ / /_/ /  __/
                               /_/    \__, //_/  \__, / .___/\___/
                                     /____/     /____/_/
```

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Do you realize what you're doing wrong here? You're centering one string that covers multiple lines, not the lines themselves. You have multiple lines of text at the start, but then you join them before centering.

Comment: I think you will be better off adding a fixed number of spaces to each line: `menulogo='\n'.join(' ' * 30 + line for line in banner ); print(menulogo)`

Comment: It may be that I need help in centring the text first then joining or there is an alternative way to centre the text

Comment: Thank you, `menulogo = '\n'.join( ' '*30+line for line in banner ); print(menulogo)`, solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `str.center()` function might work well for strings containing words, since to read them, words on different lines need not line up.

However, for ascii art, all the characters must line up vertically as well as horizontally.

You will be better off adding a fixed number of spaces to the front of each line:

```py
banner=['    ____       ______               ', '   / __ \__  _/_  __/_  ______  ___ ', '  / /_/ / / / // / / / / / __ \/ _ \ ', ' / ____/ /_/ // / / /_/ / /_/ /  __/', '/_/    \__, //_/  \__, / .___/\___/', '      /____/     /____/_/           ']

menulogo='\n'.join(' ' * 30 + line for line in banner )
print(menulogo)
```

Output appoximately as requested.

If you want to use `.center()` you would need to pad the lines to equal length and a more generic function could be done like this:

```py
def center_lines(lines, min_width, center_width):
    return '\n'.join([line.ljust(min_width).center(center_width) for line in lines])

print(center_lines(banner, 40, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.center()` for each line, but you also need to make the lines of equal length.

```
banner = [
    '    ____       ______                ',
    '   / __ \__  _/_  __/_  ______  ___  ',
    '  / /_/ / / / // / / / / / __ \/ _ \ ',
    ' / ____/ /_/ // / / /_/ / /_/ /  __/ ',
    '/_/    \__, //_/  \__, / .___/\___/  ',
    '      /____/     /____/_/            '
]

centered = [line.center(50) for line in banner]
menulogo = '\n'.join(centered)

print(menulogo)

                ____       ______                       
               / __ \__  _/_  __/_  ______  ___         
              / /_/ / / / // / / / / / __ \/ _ \        
             / ____/ /_/ // / / /_/ / /_/ /  __/        
            /_/    \__, //_/  \__, / .___/\___/         
                  /____/     /____/_/
```